# Outside Website Custom Search in Joomla

Tags: php, html, url, search, joomla3.0

I need to create a custom search box that leads to an outside url and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this in Joomla 3.0

For example: We need to create a text field with character input and have a button that when clicked takes the data in the text field and inserts it into the "**variable**" part of this URL and then takes you to this URL:

https://forexample.com/storefront/search.do;jsessionid=CD66CBFCC5658D6C9327AA269764EBB2?searchType=keyword&keyword="**variable**"&emailAddress=

Comment: Don't know why this got voted down. Not looking for a full blown solution, just need some advice on where I should start/begin or look into a certain programming language to get this functionality. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var variable = $("#textbox").val();
    window.location.replace("yoururl&" + variable);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ortix92! I will look further into jQuery for a possible solution.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please consider marking it as the actual answer :)

Comment: So I did a lot of google research and I think I have to define the libraries and it looks like the best way to do that is using Google's. How would you implement this jQuery into Joomla knowing my goal? Trying to put the writers perspective on his own code...

Comment: What if it was written this way instead?
var url = 'https://forexample.com/...&keyword=';
$('button').click(function() {
      window.location.replace(url + $('#textbox').val());
});

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you are with jQuery, but you simply include the jQuery library into your header. Then you write the code like I did above, store it in a .js file and include that also in your header (after jquery obviously). Then once the button is clicked it will fire the code above.

BTW, what you described will work too, what I did is just cleaner